# What is the benefit of leaving data in the stroage area instead of the log?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage

I did not write English well and used a translator. sorry :3

I would like to know the benefit of leaving data in the storage area rather than using the event log.

I know gas consumption has less log.

So when developing a smart contract, can not everything be an event log? I thought.

I would like to know what is essential to leave data in stroage.

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the blockchain to create a record. A log may be enough.

Contracts cannot read the log. So, if a contract needs to check a stored value, you need to store the value in a state variable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you ! it`s very helpful ^^